# Docker Compose 2 Node Elasticsearch cluster with Kibana

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I' having issues setting up my docker-compose.yml file to get 2 Elasticsearch nodes running with Kibana.

Getting the error `'Kibana server is not ready yet'`

In the container logs I'm getting

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-04-11T13:19:45Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":7,"message":"No living connections"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-04-11T13:19:45Z","tags":["warning","plugins","licensing"],"pid":7,"message":"License information could not be obtained from Elasticsearch due to Error: No Living connections error"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-04-11T13:19:45Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":7,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
```

My docker-compose.yml file looks as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: pipeup
      MYSQL_USER: pu_admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network
  #Redis
  cache:
    image: redis:rc-alpine3.11
    container_name: cache
    ports:
      - "6382:6379"
    networks:
      - app-network

  # Elasticsearch 
  elasticsearch01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
    container_name: elasticsearch01
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch01,elasticsearch02
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - node.name=elasticsearch01
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - app-network

  elasticsearch02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
    container_name: elasticsearch02
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch01
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch01,elasticsearch02
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - node.name=elasticsearch02
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - app-network

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.2
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - "elasticsearch.hosts=http://elasticsearch:9200"
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the host like this and point to one of the containers.

Change your docker-compose.yml to this:

```yaml
kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.2
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch01:9200" # Change this
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you should set the `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS` environment variable correctly :

```
kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.2
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=["http://elasticsearch01:9200","http://elasticsearch02:9200"]
```

This shows how to set this environment varibale to be picked by Kibana container for multiple elasticsearch hosts (I have just tested it).

If you just want one host then use :

```
kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.2
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch01:9200
```